# Automate Box Method / Area Model for Polynomial Division in LaTeX

Tags: tables, arrays, exam

I am writing worksheets with polynomial division using area models (often called "box method"):

[image]

The process is very slow for making dozens of problems, especially when the problems are bigger, like dividing a 5th degree polynomial by a 3rd degree polynomial. Is there a way to automate the creation of these box divisions in the future?

I would like to be able to type something like `\polyboxdiv{6x^3+25x^2-24x+11}{x+5}` (similar to `\polylongdiv{6x^3+25x^2-24x+11}{x+5}`from the `polynom` package) to automatically generate the box division representation.

Here is a [link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/ddfrprxnbrst) to the MWE:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,enumitem,bm,cancel,thmtools,physics}
\usepackage{multicol} %see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398127/breaking-a-list-into-multiple-columns-in-latex
\usepackage{multirow,array} %Used for the "hand-made" payoff matrix
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{polynom} %for polynomial long division and synthetic division, see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/polynom/polynom.pdf
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%For solution tables, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133397/printanswer-in-table-in-exam-class
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\st}[1]{\ifprintanswers\begingroup\Solution@Emphasis#1\if@shadedsolutions%
{\cellcolor{white}}
\else
\fi\endgroup\else\phantom{#1}\fi}
\makeatother
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{black}} %color font solutions
%\unframedsolutions  %Not necessary for table environment
%\shadedsolutions    %gives background color to solutions
\printanswers

\begin{document}
\section{Polynomials Division Test}
\begin{questions}

\question[40]
For the division problem
\begin{equation*}
(6x^3+25x^2-24x+11) \divisionsymbol (x+5)
\end{equation*}
\begin{parts}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\part Divide using an area model with a left divisor.
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.25cm}}|*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.25cm}|}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\st{6x^2}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\st{-5x}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\st{+1}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\ \hhline{~----}
\multirow{2}*{} $\st{x}$   & $\st{6x^3}$    & $\st{-5x^2}$   & $\st{x}$ & $\st{6}$ \\ \hhline{~----}
                $\st{+5}$  & $\st{30x^2}$   & $\st{-25x}$    & $\st{5}$ & \cellcolor{black!10} \\ \hhline{~----}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}
\columnbreak
\part Divide using an area model with an upper divisor.
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.25cm}}|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.25cm}|}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\st{x}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\st{+5}$} \\ \hhline{~--}
\multirow{2}*{} $\st{6x^2}$ & $\st{6x^3}$   & $\st{30x^2}$          \\ \hhline{~--}
                $\st{-5x}$  & $\st{-5x^2}$  & $\st{-25x}$           \\ \hhline{~--}
                $\st{+1}$   & $\st{x}$      & $\st{5}$              \\ \hhline{~--}
                            & $\st{6}$      & \cellcolor{black!10}  \\ \hhline{~--}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\part Divide using the classic long-division algorithm.
\begin{solution}
\begin{center}
\polylongdiv{6x^3+25x^2-24x+11}{x+5}
\end{center}
\end{solution}
\columnbreak
\part Divide using Horner's method of synthetic division.
\begin{solution}
\begin{center}
\polyhornerscheme[x=-5]{6x^3+25x^2-24x+11}
\end{center}
\end{solution}
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) directly into your question instead of just providing a link to overleaf. See also: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8402/134144

Comment: I think I accidentally deleted the MWE during an edit, but it's back now. Thank you!

Comment: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`

Comment: They won't match because the widths of the preceding stuff differ and `\vln` is just being used in the content of cells rather than between them.

Comment: The `sagetex` package lets you incorporate a computer algebra system into your LaTeX. This helps with automation and with many other math problems you are working with. See, for example, my answer to the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369759/setting-up-a-quadratic-equation-factoring-worksheet-how-to-get-rid-of-unwanted/369762#369762).

Comment: Another option is to consider using pythonTeX, look at its gallery - there is a step-by-step solution of integrals. The same principle should be applicable also to polynomial division.
Surely it will have better perfomance, but might need some extra setup (to get the right display, that is taken care of by polynom).

Comment: @TomášKruliš The polynom package doesn't support area models / box method long divisions last I checked. (It only supports the "classic" long division representation.) This question is about an efficient way to generate _box_ representations.

Answer (score 1):

I can help with a partial answer: how to automate the problem. The formatting, however, is quite tedious. Your top row is the quotient and the box in the rightmost column is your remainder. The computer algebra system [SAGE](https://www.sagemath.org/), which is Python based, can easily tell us the quotient and remainder with `q,r = numerator.quo_rem(denominator)`. The function `FormatTerm(a,deg)` will help format the individual terms and the function `PolyBoxDivL(f,g)` will format the table. Not as nicely as you wanted, though.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,enumitem,bm,cancel,thmtools,physics}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sagetex}          %gives us access to SAGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Polynomials Division Test}
\begin{sagesilent}
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)    #### Ring of polynomials with integer coefficients
def FormatTerm(a,deg):
    if deg == 0:
        return "$%s$"%(a)

    if deg == 1:
        if a == 1:
            return "$x$"
        elif a == -1:
            return "$-x$"
        else:
            return "$%s x$"%(a)

    if deg >1:
        if a == 1:
            return "$x^{%s}$"%(deg)
        else:
            return "$%s x^{%s}$"%(a,deg)

def PolyBoxDivL(f,g):
    numerator = f
    denominator = g
    q,r = numerator.quo_rem(denominator)
    degreeq = q.degree()
    length = q.number_of_terms()+2   ##### +1 to include the remainder and vertical poly
    width = g.number_of_terms()
########### Table header    
    output = r""
    output += r"\begin{tabular}{c|"+"c|"*(length)+"}"
    output += r"\cline{2-%s}"%(length)
    output += r" & "
    for i in range(degreeq,-1,-1):
        if q[i] != 0:
            output += r"%s & "%(FormatTerm(q[i],i))
    output += r"\rule{0pt}{13pt} \\[6pt]\cline{2-%s}"%(length)
#### rows which aren't the header 

    for i in range(g.degree(),-1,-1):
        if denominator[i] != 0:
            output += r"\rule{0pt}{18pt} %s &"%(FormatTerm(denominator[i],i))
            for j in range(q.degree(),-1,-1):
                if q[j] != 0:
                    output += r"%s & "%(FormatTerm(denominator[i]*q[j],i+j))
            if i == g.degree():
                output += r"$%s$ \\[8pt]\cline{2-%s}"%(latex(r),length)
            else:
                output += r"\cellcolor{black!10} \\[8pt]\cline{2-%s}"%(length)
    output += r"\end{tabular}"

    return output
\end{sagesilent}

Use the area model with a left divisor to find $(6x^3+25x^2-24x+11)   \divisionsymbol (x+5)$:\\\\
\begin{sagesilent}
Q1 = PolyBoxDivL(6*x^3+25*x^2-24*x+11,x+5)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{Q1}

\vspace{.5cm}
Use the area model with a left divisor to find $(5x^5-3x^2+x-1) \divisionsymbol (x^2+x+1)$:\\\\
\begin{sagesilent}
Q2 = PolyBoxDivL(5*x^5-3*x^2+x-1,x^2+x+1)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{Q2}

\vspace{.5cm}
Use the area model with a left divisor to find $(x^4-1) \divisionsymbol (x^2-1)$:\\\\
\begin{sagesilent}
Q3 = PolyBoxDivL(x^4-1,x^2-1)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{Q3}

\vspace{.5cm}
Use the area model with a left divisor to find $(x^9-7x^4) \divisionsymbol (x^3-x+4)$:\\\\
\begin{sagesilent}
Q4 = PolyBoxDivL(x^9-7*x^4,x^3-x+4)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{Q4}
\end{document}
```

SAGE is not part of LaTeX. It needs to be downloaded to your machine or, even easier, accessed through a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. 
The code running in Cocalc looks like this:

[image]

A very important line to notice is `output += r"\begin{tabular}{c|"+"c|"*(length)+"}"`. This allows the table to vary the number of columns because SAGE can calculate the number of nonzero terms needed to calculate the number of columns. The area model with an upper(?) divisor is handled in similar fashion. The problem is calculated by `\begin{sagesilent}
Q4 = PolyBoxDivL(x^9-7*x^4,x^3-x+4)
\end{sagesilent}` and then placing the resulting string into the document with `\sagestr{Q4}`.

**EDIT:** In response to comments below, I've added 0 coefficient terms so that the exponents are the same on diagonals. I don't know how to get the table formatting to handle vertical lines for some rows. I've chosen to color the cells to resolve the problem

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
     \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,enumitem,bm,cancel,thmtools,physics}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sagetex}          %gives us access to SAGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Polynomials Division Test}
\begin{sagesilent}
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)    #### Ring of polynomials with integer   coefficients
def FormatTerm(a,deg):
    if deg == 0:
        return "$%s$"%(a)

    if deg == 1:
        if a == 1:
            return "$x$"
        elif a == -1:
            return "$-x$"
        else:
            return "$%s x$"%(a)

    if deg >1:
        if a == 1:
            return "$x^{%s}$"%(deg)
        else:
            return "$%s x^{%s}$"%(a,deg)

def PolyBoxDivL(f,g):
    numerator = f
    denominator = g
    q,r = numerator.quo_rem(denominator)
    length = q.degree()+3
    width = g.degree()+1
########### Table header    
    output = r""
    output += r"\begin{tabular}{"+"c"*(length)+"}"
    output += r" & "
    for i in range(q.degree(),-1,-1):
        output += r" \cellcolor{black!10} %s & "%(FormatTerm(q[i],i))
    output += r"\rule{0pt}{13pt} \\[6pt]"
#### rows which aren't the header

    for i in range(g.degree(),-1,-1):
        output += r"\rule{0pt}{18pt} \cellcolor{black!10} %s &"%(FormatTerm(denominator[i],i))
        for j in range(q.degree(),-1,-1):
            output += r"\cellcolor{orange!10} %s & "%(FormatTerm(denominator[i]*q[j],i+j))
        if i == g.degree():
            output += r"\cellcolor{blue!10} $%s$ \\[8pt]"%(latex(r))
        else:
            output += r"\cellcolor{blue!10} \\[8pt]"
    output += r"\end{tabular}"

    return output
\end{sagesilent}

Use the area model with a left divisor to find $(6x^3+25x^2-24x+11)     \divisionsymbol (x+5)$:\\\\
\begin{sagesilent}
Q1 = PolyBoxDivL(6*x^3+25*x^2-24*x+11,x+5)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{Q1}

\vspace{.5cm}
Use the area model with a left divisor to find $(5x^5-3x^2+x-1) \divisionsymbol (x^2+x+1)$:\\\\
\begin{sagesilent}
Q2 = PolyBoxDivL(5*x^5-3*x^2+x-1,x^2+x+1)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{Q2}

\vspace{.5cm}
Use the area model with a left divisor to find $(x^4-1) \divisionsymbol (x^2-1)$:\\\\
\begin{sagesilent}
Q3 = PolyBoxDivL(x^4-1,x^2-1)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{Q3}

\vspace{.5cm}
Use the area model with a left divisor to find $(x^9-7x^4) \divisionsymbol (x^3-x+4)$:\\\\
\begin{sagesilent}
Q4 = PolyBoxDivL(x^9-7*x^4,x^3-x+4)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{Q4}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will look into learning Sage. Is there some way to remove the table lines / rules around the quotient? This way, both the divisor and quotient are "outside" the box?

Comment: There might be; I searched and found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31441/vertical-line-only-in-one-part-of-a-table) but I found myself wasting too much time  getting the formatting like your example. I just don't know much about table formatting.

Comment: Hi DJP, I like that you were able to remove the gridlines/table rules for the box lengths/dimensions along the left, so the numbers appear "outside" the table. Is it possible to use the same approach for the numbers along the top row, so they also appear "outside" the table?

Comment: Also, a nice feature of area models is the exponents along the diagonals are always equal. In the first three of your examples this is the case, but not in the fourth example. I think this is because there aren't "placeholder" rows & columns, e.g. a 0x^2 row and 0x^5 column. Is this modification possible? Thanks again!

Comment: @Mathemanic it's almost certainly possible for the numbers to be outside the table. I only use tables in a most basic form (vertical lines to separate, avoid "cells") so I don't know how that's typically done. As I mentioned in my 2nd comment, I was wasting too much time on formatting issues when main issue had been solved. As long as there is a rule to do it programmatically it has to be possible. I'm not seeing the diagonal in second case being equal (looks like 3, 3, 2) so I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want.

Comment: @Mathemanic maybe the problem with exponents not being the same is due to some of the terms missing (eg an x^2 and no x^1). In area models is there usually a box when the coefficient is 0? (eg 0x^1)

Comment: Hi DJP, thanks for your reply! Yes, I think the missing terms is the cause of the exponents not matching up. For example in your last example, there should be a row for 0x^2, and a column for 0x^5. (It's a silly row because all of the entries are 0x^8, 0x^7, 0x^6, 0x^5, 0x^4, 0x^3, 0x^2, 0x, 0) but it helps the exponents match up. Is this modification possible?

Comment: @Mathemanic I've posted the revised code. To avoid burning time on table formatting, I've colored the cells to make it easier to see the key aspects of the box method.

Answer (score 0):

What I am describing is not an answer but something to point you in the right direction

Since it will not fit in the comments column I am posting it here

Hope the mods will not mind!

What you are asking is to

- Parse the value of the polynomial into a tabular environment
- The table design varies to four different designs
- The process is automated from the time you feed in the polynomial in the numerator and denominator portion

Please see the answers on this website at

[Automatically creating a table from datatool using references in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153335/automatically-creating-a-table-from-datatool-using-references-in-the-text)

[Formatting complex table from CSV using datatool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17618/formatting-complex-table-from-csv-using-datatool?rq=1)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
  Hammer001,   Hammer,    1 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , light (add some words here to wrap around)
  Hammer002,   Hammer,    2 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , heavy
  Hammer003,   Hammer,    3 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , really heavy
  Longsword001,Longsword, 1 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , one-handed
  Longsword002,Longsword, 2 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , two-handed
  Longsword003,Longsword, 3 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , three-handed
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\PrintDTLTable}[2][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
  \begin{longtable}{l l l l l l l m{2in}}
  & \colhead{Label} & \colhead{Cost} & \colhead{Weight} &
    \colhead{PropA} & \colhead{PropB} & \colhead{PropC} & \colhead{Description}\\
  \hline
  \DTLforeach
    [%
     \(\equal{#1}{}\AND\DTLisSubString{\ReferencedIDs}{\RowID}\)
     \OR
     \(\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}\AND\DTLisSubString{\ReferencedIDs}{\RowID}\)%
    ]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Label=Label,%
      \Cost=Cost,%
      \Weight=Weight,%
      \PropA=PropA,%
      \PropB=PropB,%
      \PropC=PropC,%
      \Description=Description%
     }{%
       \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Label &\Cost & \Weight & \PropA & \PropB & \PropC & \Description \\
    }%
    \end{longtable}
}

\makeatletter
\let\oldref\ref
\def\ref#1{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\gappto\string\ReferencedIDs{#1,}%
  }%
  \oldref{#1}%
}
\def\ReferencedIDs{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

% \DTLsetseparator{&}% Define separator of the data
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Label,Cost,Weight,PropA,PropB,PropC,Description}]{myDB}{\jobname.dat}

% \DTLdisplaydb{myDB}% Useful for debugging.

\PrintDTLTable[Hammer001,Hammer003,Longsword003]{myDB}

\PrintDTLTable[Hammer002,Longsword002]{myDB}

This is a reference to ~\ref{Hammer003}.

This is a reference to ~\ref{Longsword002}.

\end{document}
```

Output in tabular form is as below

[image]

The first part of the code

`\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
  Hammer001,   Hammer,    1 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , light (add some words here to wrap around)
  Hammer002,   Hammer,    2 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , heavy
  Hammer003,   Hammer,    3 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , really heavy
  Longsword001,Longsword, 1 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , one-handed
  Longsword002,Longsword, 2 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , two-handed
  Longsword003,Longsword, 3 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , three-handed
\end{filecontents*}`

is similar to advertising the polynomial which is then parsed into a table form

There are similar queries on the webpage which you may like to explore

[image]

I am sure one of the experts on this site will shortly get back to you